# MEAN stack - Error while loading AngularJS script

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I'm 100% new to MEAN stack and currently trying to self-study it with the help of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI) by Michael Moser (If you're reading this, thank you for making such an easy-to-understand video! :) ). I'm trying to make a very basic program with CRUD functionalities, but I can't get past this particular error message when loading the Angular JS file. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Here are my codes:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "starter-node-angular",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.5.1",
    "method-override": "~2.0.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.0"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
// modules needed
// express - middleware
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();

// listens for request to server and throws main.html as response
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/main.html');
});

// listens for request to server with 'scripts' in it and returns the appropriate file declared
// in the script tag
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/client/scripts'));

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Ready...");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="ProductApp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="main-background" ng-controller="MainController">
    <!-- Area for Logo and Search Bar -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="main-logo">
            STUFF - Product Inventory v1.0
        </div>

        <div class="main-search">
            <input type="text" class="search-field" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
            <img src="images/search-icon.png" title="Search" class="search-ico" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Area for Add Button -->
    <div class="add-container">
        <div class="add-button" ng-click="addProduct(test);">
            <img src="images/add-icon.png" title="Add" class="add-ico" />
            <span class="add-text">Add Product</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ProductApp', []);

// Main controller
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // Search Products
    $scope.searchProduct = function (param) {
        // Search fxn goes here...
    }

    // Add products
    $scope.addProduct = function (param) {
        alert('Add product');
    }

    // Edit Products 
    $scope.updateProduct = function (param) {
        // Update fxn goes here...
    }

    // Delete Product 
    $scope.deleteProduct = function (param) {
        // Delete fxn goes here
    }
}]);
```

I came from a background where calling JS files was simply declaring the full path in the `src`. Tbh, I find the entire MEAN setup a bit complex, with the "middleware" concept and all. :( I appreciate MongoDB's role in it, though.

Anyways, any help and advice would be greatly appreciated. God knows I need a lot of it right now.

Thank you.

**Update 1:**
I tried changing how my `<script>` tag calls my angular like so, with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/users/myusername/documents/practice/product db/client/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Also, am I right in thinking that `localhost:3000` refers to **Product DB** in the following directory structure? I'm aware that `3000` is the port number; after looking at my error logs, I was thinking that `localhost` is just an alias for the source folder of the app.

[image]

Complete path is C:\users\myusername\documents\Practice\Product DB...

Thank you, as always. :)

Comment: Can you confirm if all files are loaded on the page properly?

Comment: The errors all point to your scripts just not being found, so the app can't boot up. You can see the requests for all kinds of things failing (your css files, etc). In index.html, check your baseref attribute (should be first one in the header section), and otherwise make sure the app knows where to find those files (especially main.js). What happens if you try something like './client/scripts/main.js', etc.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to confirm that but, the HTML loads whenever I call `localhost:3000`. I can't say the same for my JS and CSS, though.

Comment: Sure, index.html is found at that address. After that though, index.html pulls in other files. The paths you have set up for those files aren't being found by index.html. They're just not loading. You need to work on how those paths are set up so that index.html can pull them in.

Comment: Does that mean I don't need to call `app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/client/scripts'));`? @TimConsolazio

Comment: @TimConsolazio says that the javascript file in which you have the angulatjs module and controllers is not being loaded. For testing, try referring that file in your html page and the app should work without errors

Comment: I think you need to add something to server your other static files (other then scripts) to your server.js. something like:     app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname , "/")));

Comment: Hello, I've updated my post to reflect my attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included `ng-app` in the `HTML` tag, try adding that in the `body` of the page.

**Do this:**

`<body class="main-background" ng-app="ProductApp" ng-controller="MainController">`

**Update:**

you have done few mistakes while fetching **stylesheets** and **scripts** both. You need to define a proper **static route** which will work for all the `static files(stylesheets and scripts)`.

you had defined yous static routed like this:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/client/scripts'));
```

This will tell the node app to look into `client/scripts` folder, if any `static` route starts with `/scripts`. But you are trying to fetch your `script` using `src="/client/scripts/main.js"` which will not get anything, as `/client` is not defined , nor default '/' route is defined. It should be `src="/scripts/main.js"` instead.

One more mistake is while fetching `stylesheets`. you are using `href="/styles/main.css"`,  where again neither `/styles` nor `/` is defined, thus it will not be able to get the `css` file.

**Try this instead:**

**Server.js**

```
//define static routes like this
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
// this will tell node app to look into the client folder, for any static file
```

**HTML:**

Fetch all your files like below:

**To get stylesheets :**

use **`/styles/filename`**

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This will look into `styles` folder inside `client` folder.

**To get scripts :**

use **`/scripts/filename`**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

This will look into `scripts` folder inside `client` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Finally managed to make it work. :)